# how to include my test in application jar

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle build in my java application. My project has the elasticsearch intergation test. Following is my gradle.build

```
jar {
    baseName = 'myproject'
    version = 'V.4.0.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.myapp.Application'
    }
     from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
test {
    systemProperties = System.properties
    systemProperty 'tests.security.manager', 'false'
}
```

When i give `gradle build` it executed the test and created the `myproject-V.4.0.0.jar`. but when i run the

```
java -cp myproject-V.4.0.0.jar;junit-4.11.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.myapp.test.testclassname
```

i got class not found exception for com.myapplication.test.testclassname.
I extracted the myproject-V.4.0.0.jar and can not find the test class.

My question is, How can i include the test class also in my application jar?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? You typically DON'T want to ship your tests with your application jar

Comment: @tddmonkey, yes, But the problem is i will have to give my integration test to be exectuted now and then. It will not be deployed in PRD. for PRD i will be having a clean build without any test included. how ever i need to ship one copy of my application with the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a deliberate behaviour of gradle java projects. A jar is your production artifact, so usually you want to test it during the build, but you do not want to run your tests in production, so I do not recommend doing it. Having said that, there is a way of doing it in gradle, like this:

```
task myJar(type:Jar) {
from {sourceSets.main.output  + sourceSets.test.output}
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at the created jar, like list the files and check it out. I have tried it and it does include the class for me. If you can't find the class, then can you write the exact path to the test file in your project? Are you using the gradle java plugin?

Comment: My test is added but the problem is, It adds only .java files not my .class files

Comment: Can you double check you add `output` in the configuration definition? and not `allSource`? If you still have the issue, maybe you could make the project with the file structure (no content in classes required) and your build.gradle file in some public repo to have a look at it?